# TCPDF report not showing all rows

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

As you can see in the title, I've tried generating a simple pdf report by using a mysql query using CodeIgniter's query function, the query looks like this:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * 
                    FROM v_complaint 
                    WHERE datetime BETWEEN $firstdate' AND '$seconddate' 
                    ORDER BY datetime DESC")
    ->result();
```

and the foreach looks like this:

```
foreach ($query as $row){
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->name,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->title,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->datetime,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->action_datetime,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->category_name,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row->status,1,0);
}
```

but when the pdf is ran, I only have 1 row showing, where as in phpmyadmin, there are 2 rows, keep in my mind they are using the exact same query:

TCPDF:
[image: TCPDF]

PHPMYADMIN:
[image: PHPMYADMIN]

I found no obvious reason why this would be happening, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: prob need a `$pdf->Ln();` at end of each iteration

Comment: It works! thanks, I don't know why ln() is needed here because in previous pdf generates rows automatically go down a line